# Find row with closest first element

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like

```
a = [ 4.1    45    65    84    84 , 
      4.2    62    78    83    43 , 
      4.3    84    94    93    94 ]
```

and a vector like

```
b = [ 4.123  4.21   4.31   4.19 ]
```

For every element in vector `b`, I want to find the row in `a`, for which the element in the first column is closest to this element from `b`.
Finally, I want to concatenate the elements of `b` and the corresponding row to form a new matrix `c`.

So the final matrix looks like

```
c = [ 4.123   45    65    84    84 ,
      4.21    62    78    83    43 , 
      4.31    84    94    93    94 ,
      4.19    62    78    83    43 ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`bsxfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) function to create a matrix, which contains the difference between each element in `b` and each element of the first column of `a`:

```
bsxfun(@minus,b,a(:,1))
ans =
   -0.0230   -0.1100   -0.2100   -0.0900
    0.0770   -0.0100   -0.1100    0.0100
    0.1770    0.0900   -0.0100    0.1100
```

Each row of the matrix corresponds to one element in `a(:,1)`, and each column to one element in `b`. i.e. the element `(3,1)` is equal to `b(1)-a(3,1)`.

To find the nearest values, let's look at the absolute values `abs()` and find the smallest value of every column using the [`min`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) function. The first return value of `min` is the minimal value of each column, the second return value is the index. We only need the index, so we discard the first return value using `~`.

```
[~,minRow] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus,a(:,1),b)))
minRow =
     1     2     3     2
```

We now know, which row of `a` we have to use, so we can construct the matrix by concatenating `b` and the correct row of `a` into one matrix:

```
c = [ b.', a(minRow,2:end) ];
c =
    4.1230   45.0000   65.0000   84.0000   84.0000
    4.2100   62.0000   78.0000   83.0000   43.0000
    4.3100   84.0000   94.0000   93.0000   94.0000
    4.1900   62.0000   78.0000   83.0000   43.0000
```